# Ajax undefined value in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

When I call the function I always get an undefined value, I don't understand what can ruin it.

> You are logged in as undefined, Error undefined

***Ajax script:***

```
function Submit() {
   console.log('asd')

   $.ajax({
       url: "Server.php",
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "json",
       data: {
          name: "Test2",
          email: "Test@gmail.com"
       },
       success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          console.log("You are logged in as: ", data.name);
          $('#user').html("You are logged in as: " + data.name);
       },
       error: function(request, error, data) {
          console.log(arguments);
          alert(" Can't do because: " + error + " DATA: " + data);
       }
   })
}
```

***PHP Script:***

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

$errors = [];
$data = [];

if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';
}

if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $errors['email'] = 'Email is required.';
}

if (!empty($errors)) {
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors'] = $errors;
} else {
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Success!';
    $data['name'] = $_POST['name'];
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I tried every solution in vain, so I still get an indefinite value. I’m slowly starting to think there’s nothing wrong with the script.

Comment: In your `Server.php` you should return the `data.name` if you wish to use that in your success function

Comment: That's good, but how can I do that?

Comment: success function first parameter should be the object that has the name attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use data.name but you never return name. hence the undefined.
I've added data.name in the example below and it seems to work fine.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

$errors = [];
$data = [];

if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';
}

if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $errors['email'] = 'Email is required.';
}

if (!empty($errors)) {
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors'] = $errors;
} else {
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Success!';
    $data['name'] = $_POST['name'];
}

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Also the parameters used in the succes function are in a different order than you seem to use, in your case the `request` will have your data in it

Comment: Not good because I also get undefined value.

Comment: @NexaHn what exactly did you do? `console.log(request.name);` inside the `success:function(request, data, error)` callback should output it

Answer (score 2):

the callback parameter not

```
success:function(request, data, error)
```

but

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
```

`data.name` of course `undefined` because it is `string`

and your Server.php return this

```
{"success":true,"message":"Success!"}
```

no `data.name` but `data.success` and `data.message`

so you have to write

```
if (!empty($errors)) {
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors'] = $errors;
} else {
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Success!';
    $data['name'] = $_POST['name']; // add this
}
```

Comment: Not good because I also get undefined value.

Comment: test it [here](https://phpsandbox.io/e/x/he6so)

Comment: I use it that way too, I tried to copy it. But it didn't work that way either. I don't think there's a problem with the script.